# No function matches the given name and argument type

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.udf_insertcontact(
    _pid integer,
    _firstname character varying(30),
    _lastname character varying(30),
    _emailaddress character varying(100),
    _company character varying(50),
    _category character varying,
    _gender character varying,
    _dob timestamp,
    _modeslack boolean,
    _modewhatsapp boolean,
    _modeemail boolean,
    _modephone boolean,
    _contactimage character varying)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO public.tblcontacts(
     professionid, firstname, lastname, emailaddress, company, category, gender, dob, modeslack, modewhatsapp, modeemail, modephone, contactimage)
    VALUES ( 
        _pid, _firstname, _lastname, _emailaddress, _company, _category, _gender, _dob, _modeslack, _modewhatsapp, _modeemail, _modephone, _contactimage);
    IF FOUND THEN -- INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY
    RETURN 1;
    ELSE RETURN 0; -- INSERTED FAIL
    END IF;                                                                 
END
$BODY$;
```

```
SELECT public.udf_insertcontact(2,'first','last','email@e.com','company','Client','Female',current_timestamp,false,true,false,true,'');
```

> ERROR:  function public.udf_insertcontact(integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, timestamp with time zone, boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, unknown) does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Your function is OK, You need to typecast the parameter `current_timestamp::timestamp`

This will work :

```
SELECT udf_insertcontact(2,'first','last','email@e.com','company','Client','Female',current_timestamp::timestamp,false,true,false,true,'');
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/uUOH_HE_)